# Jest passing test case while ignoring assertions which should fail

Tags: jestjs

In the following test case, the value returned doesn't match the expected value, still the test case is passed. Why?

```js
describe("Endpoints are accessible", () => {
  it("GET request for homepage should return 200", async () => {
    const baseURL = process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_TEST 
    console.log(`base url is ${baseURL}`);
    
    const req = {};
    
    const res = {};
    
    indexControllerModule.homepageHandler(req,res)
    .then((result)=>{
      console.log(`result is ${result}`);
      expect(result.message).toBe("welcome");
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(`error in accessing homepage: ${error}`);
    })
  });  
});
```

Here is the result:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --testTimeout=100 index.test.js

  console.log
    Ensure both Mongo and Express is running before running these tests

      at Object.log (test/index.test.js:8:11)

  console.log                                                                                                                  
    base url is http://localhost:4000                                                                                          

      at Object.log (test/index.test.js:14:15)

  console.log                                                                                                                  
    index page. Req [object Object]

      at Object.log [as homepageHandler] (controllers/index.js:8:13)

  console.log                                                                                                                  
    result is {"message":"welcome"}                                                                                            

      at log (test/index.test.js:22:17)

  console.log
    error in accessing homepage: Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "welcome"
    Received: undefined

      at log (test/index.test.js:26:17)

 PASS  test/index.test.js <--- PASS!
  Endpoints are accessible                                                                                                     
    √ GET request for homepage should return 200 (31 ms)                                                                       
                                                                                                                               
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                 
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                 
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.677 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites matching /index.test.js/i.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Jest is not awaiting for your `expect()` call. You are not awaiting anything, so Jest just thinks there is no assertion, so it succeeds.

You can solve this in 2 different ways:

- The `await` way
- The callback way

##### The `await` way

Just convert your `.then()` to `await`:

```js
describe("Endpoints are accessible", () => {
  it("GET request for homepage should return 200", async () => {
    const baseURL = process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_TEST 
    console.log(`base url is ${baseURL}`);
    
    const req = {};
    
    const res = {};
    
    const result = await indexControllerModule.homepageHandler(req, res)
    console.log(`result is ${result}`);

    expect(result.message).toBe("welcome");
  });  
});
```

You don't need your `.catch()` (which would have to be converted to a `try {} catch {}`) because the thrown error will already make your test fail. And the error will already be logged.

IMO, the above solution is the **best approach**.

##### The callback way

You can use the `done` callback of `it()`, and **remove the `async` keyword**. Mixing `done` and `async` is bad practice, and the latest version of Jest added an error message to prevent this IIRC.

The following will ensure Jest waits that you call `done()` or `done.fail()` to finish the test.

```js
describe("Endpoints are accessible", () => {
  it("GET request for homepage should return 200", (done) => {
    const baseURL = process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_TEST 
    console.log(`base url is ${baseURL}`);
    
    const req = {};
    
    const res = {};
    
    indexControllerModule.homepageHandler(req,res)
    .then((result)=>{
      console.log(`result is ${result}`);
      expect(result.message).toBe("welcome");
      done()
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(`error in accessing homepage: ${error}`);
      done.fail()
    })
  });  
});
```